# Perl - How can I turn a hash into a query string?

Tags: perl, hash

How can I turn a hash into a query string? I would like to find a solution that doesn't involve using the CGI module. Here's an example of what I'm wanting to do but don't know what the best and most elegant approach would be, since I'm relatively new to Perl.

Hash:

```
my $data = {
         'key1' => 'value1',
         'key2' => 'value2',
         'key3' => 'value3',
         'key4' => 'value4'
};
```

To desired query string:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use URI qw( );
my $url = URI->new('', 'http');
$url->query_form(%$data);
my $query = $url->query;
```

If you're actually trying to build a POST request, check out [HTTP::Request::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP::Request::Common)'s `POST`.

Comment: Note if you want to get the url with the querystring in it use `$url->as_string`

Comment: @Matthew Lock, Nah, you don't need to do that. Just use `$url`. It will automatically stringify to the URL.