# Turn Query String into Hash Perl

Tags: perl, hash, uri

I want to find out how to do the opposite of this:

[Perl - How can I turn a hash into a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281332/perl-how-can-i-turn-a-hash-into-a-query-string)

I have a query string form that is stringified and want to convert it to a hash.

With more context, a client is passing some URL params as a stringified query form which is base64 encoded, and I wanted to decode, turn into a hash, add some more custom URL parameters to the hash, then I have a method that already converts back to a string and appends to the URL.

```
my $uriQuery = URI::Query->new($redirectQueryParams);
$qs = $uriQuery->hash;
```

Seems to blow up with

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "URI::Query"

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow is probably not the best place for your question.

Comment: This is easily solved with a quick search of CPAN. And please at least include your query string so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: my $uriQuery = URI::Query->new($redirectQueryParams);
        $qs = $uriQuery->hash;

Seems to blow up with Can't locate object method "new" via package "URI::Query"

Comment: And how is that not working? You already listed down the steps you need to take. Which ones of them do you need help with exactly? Certainly you do not expect us to do all the work for you.

Comment: It seems as though that URI::Query module doesn't exist for some reason, so thought there may be another way to approach this.

Comment: Besides that your code is not strict, I could run it. I have a URI::Query 0.16 installed in my system. It's not part of the battle-tested URI distribution that's in turn part of the LWP, and it has not seen much development, but it's there on CPAN. https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/URI-Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module in conjunction with the drop-in addon [URI::QueryParams](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::QueryParam) can do what you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my $uri = URI->new('https://example.org/?foo=bar&baz=qrr');
$uri->query_param_append(frobnication => 'yes, please');

print $uri;
```

This will print

```
https://example.org/?foo=bar&baz=qrr&frobnication=yes%2C+please
```

If you actually wanted a hash, you could call [the `query_form_hash` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::QueryParam#$u-%3Equery_form_hash(-%5C%25new_form-)).

```
$uri->query_form_hash
```

However, that doesn't make much sense considering that all the alterations you could think of are already implemented.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but that's the opposite of what I need. I just want to convert a query string into a hash, add some more items to the hash and then use - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281332/perl-how-can-i-turn-a-hash-into-a-query-string to convert back to a query.

So the input should be:

foo=bar&baz=qrr

and the output:

$data = {
         'foo' => 'bar',
         'baz' => 'qrr',
};

I can then add:

$data->{more} = 'yes';

convert back to query using:

$url->query_form(%$data);

Comment: @snakespan I understand that. But I'm saying you don't need to. This module already does **all the work** for you. See my edit for how you can do the hard work yourself if you really need to.